# Drawerlayout.Open Method not working in Samsung mobiles

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Hi i'm stuck in problem that drawer layout is not open in samsung mobile but toggle icon changes in back icon.
Thanks in advance
Here is code please help me to get Rid from it.

```
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout);
                if (usersInfo.getIsOwner().equalsIgnoreCase("true") || usersInfo.getIsManager().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                    if (currentFragment instanceof ReportsMapFragment ||
                            currentFragment instanceof UsersInfoFragment || currentFragment instanceof MyProfileFragment ||
                            currentFragment instanceof MyTransactionFragment || currentFragment instanceof AboutUsFragment) {
                        if (currentFragment instanceof AboutUsFragment)
                            navigationViewLeft.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_about_us);
                        else if (currentFragment instanceof MyTransactionFragment)
                            navigationViewLeft.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_transactions);
                        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    } else {
                        onBackPressed();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (currentFragment instanceof ReportDetailMapFragment || currentFragment instanceof MyProfileFragment || currentFragment instanceof AboutUsFragment) {
                        if (currentFragment instanceof AboutUsFragment)
                            navigationViewLeft.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_about_us);
                        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    } else {
                        onBackPressed();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: add full cde and Layou

Comment: There mistake in the Xml file , i got my solution but don't know why its is working in other devices.